# can I run new WP_Query inside the Loop with no affects to the Loop? (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

the bellow function is working fine but I need to run it inside the loop. If done so the post content is actually taken from the last post of my WP_Query. Not from the one that should appear.

Is there any way to run my query and leave **The Loop unaffected**?

```
function recent_post_by_author() {
  echo '<div class="recent_post_by_author">';
  $my_query = new WP_Query('author_name=Radek&showposts=2');
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a><BR>
  <?php endwhile;
  echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The fix for this is to call [wp_reset_postdata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after you're done looping through your separate WP_Query instance.

The problem is showing up because WordPress uses a global `$post` variable that is set whenever a call to `the_post()` is made on any WP_Query object. When you call it from your 2-posts-from-Radek query, it loses track of the original WP_Query object.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing some php opening and closing tags when enclosing the new query in the function? This works as a standalone new query loop that can be used multiple times inside the main WP loop:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('author_name=Radek&showposts=2'); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using the new query in a function? Do you need to do that?

Comment: Are you sure it won't affect my already running loop? If yes, then I'm in luck coz I need to do this.

Comment: This won't solve the problem the problem he's having -- `$my_query->the_post();` modifies the global `$post` variable, leaving it attached to his new query.

Comment: Thanks Nate this should be an answer not a comment :)